# Failure in importing typescript files from node_module @zilliqa-js/util

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

I tried to import some classes (included in some typescript files) from a node module called @zilliqa-js/util in my index.html page.
For doing this I put the following script tag in the body of index.html...

```
<script type="module" src="/js/zilliqa.js"></script>
```

First I tried with a non-relative import..
...I created the following file zilliqa.js  in the folder ./public/js with the following import statement...

```
import { BN, Long, bytes, units } from "zilliqa-js/util";
```

In the moment the classes { BN, Long, bytes, units } are imported they throw the error:

'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "zilliqa-js/util". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".'

Second I tried with a relative import...
...I created the following file zilliqa.js  in the folder ./public/js with the following import statement...

```
import { BN, Long, bytes, units } from "../node_modules/@zilliqa-js/util/dist/index.d.ts";
```

In the moment the classes { BN, Long, bytes, units } are imported they throw the error:

'Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "video/mp2t". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.'

The structure of my project folder is the following...

```
root
   |
   ...
   node_modules
              |
              ...
              @zilliqa-js
                        |
                        ...
                        util
                           |
                           ...
                           package.json
                           tsconfig.json
                           dist
                           ...
```

...the content of the tsconfig.json is...

````
```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
  "rootDir": "src",
  "outDir": "dist"
},
  "include": ["src", "../../typings/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```
````

The content of the package.json is...

```
{
  "name": "@zilliqa-js/util",
  "version": "0.11.1",
  "description": "Utilities for working with Zilliqa.",
  "author": "Ian Tan (https://github.com/iantanwx)",
  "maintainers": [
    "Zilliqa Usability Team <maintainer@zilliqa.com> (https://github.com/zilliqa/)"
  ],
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Zilliqa/Zilliqa-JavaScript-Library/issues"
  },
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "node": "dist/index.js",
  "browser": "dist/index.umd.js",
  "module": "dist/index.esm.js",
  "jsnext:main": "dist/index.esm.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "repository": "https://github.com/zilliqa/zilliqa-javascript-library/",
  "license": "GPL-3.0",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bn.js": "^4.11.3",
    "@types/long": "^4.0.0",
    "bn.js": "^4.11.8",
    "long": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0 <13"
  },
  "gitHead": "e3a808d65e766ca5a1193a70e38cafaa37d0e7f5"
}
```

Moreover the files in the @zilliqa-js are protected and they cannot be modified.
Could you please help me in fixing this issue?

Thank you

Comment: There are a couple of typos in the text above. The second line of code is 'import { BN, Long, bytes, units } from "@zilliqa-js/util";' and the correspondent thrown error is ''Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@zilliqa-js/util". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".''

Answer (score 0):

To use Zilliqa Js in html you will need to compile Zilliqa Js to min.js file using yarn and webpack tool and then use this in your html. More instructions on this can be found in the `webpack` section Zilliqa js git page here https://github.com/Zilliqa/Zilliqa-JavaScript-Library#webpack

Make sure you install all npm dependencies packages before creating your min js in the cloned zilliqa js repo. Also if any dependency is missing like `util` one then install it seperately using `npm install` command, as it might not be included in dependency list.